# Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix such that $A^2$ is diagonalizable and $det(A)\ne 0$. Prove that A is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ complex matrix such that $A^2$ is diagonalizable and $det(A)\ne 0$. Prove that A is diagonalizable

I have no idea how to even begin the proof.

Comment: Note that there is a decomposition $A^2 = P^{-1} D P $.

Then note that if $A = P^{-1} D^{\frac{1}{2}} P$ then $A^2 = P^{-1}DP$. So you have a diagonalised version of $A$ now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Any non-diagonalizable $2\times2$ complex matrix is similar to a matrix of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\0&\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: how can we show this? and how does a non-zero determinant of $A$ factor into this

Comment: We can deduce this from the fact that every matrix has an eigenvalue. And the determinant of a matrix of that form is different from $0$ if and only if $\alpha\neq0$. It is easy to deduce from this that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\0&\alpha\end{smallmatrix}\right]^2$ is not diagonalisable, unless $\beta=0$.